# NgNewRouter viewport and navigation

Tags: angularjs, angular-new-router

Hello Angular Community:
   I'm use the ngNewRouter with Angular 1.4 for my applications and I found a series of problems or maybe not, and it is my ignorance ....
When you define a nested router, the viewport is searched only in the direct parent and not looking at the chain of definitions for routers, this, I think violates the modularity ...

For example:
    MainController define the following configuration:

```
$router.config ([
{
   path: '/ process'
   components: {
     main: 'process'
   }
},
{
   path: '/ process /: id'
   components: {
     main: 'instance'
   }
}
```

InstanceController define the following:

```
{
  path: '/ district /: id'
  components: {
    main: 'instance.details'
  }
}
```

Then, the associated template is not rendered in the viewport, but if I move settings of IntanceCntroller to MainController everything work fine.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the current release. They are currently reworking the API for 1.5 and 2.0 and - as it seems, have abandoned the current repository.

Just take a look at the issue tracker and some of the forks.